# a:not(a:not([href])) selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want that a certain action to be associated to the click event of the anchor tag whenever its `href` attribute:

- does not start with `mailto:` and
- does not end with `#` and
- is present with any value including empty

So I was trying this code:

```
<a href="example.com">example.com</a>
<a href="mailto:someone@www.example.com">Someone</a>
<a href="thepage#">The Page</a>
<a>This does nothing</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'a:not([href^="mailto\\:"], [href$="\\#"], [href])', myFunction);
</script>
```

And it didn't work. But to my dismay this works:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([href^="mailto\\:"], [href$="\\#"], a:not([href]))', myFunction);
```

But I don't understand how. Notice the inner `:not()`. As I understand the `[href]` means there is no `href` attribute. Or is it the opposite?

Could someone lead me to the light?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[href]` means there is an href attribute no matter which, if any, value it has.

As pimvdb correctly pointed out, you could use

`a[href]:not([href^="mailto\\:"], [href$="\\#"])`

Which means "all a elements with any href attribute, except those whose href attribute starts with mailto: or ends with #

Comment: True, he may want a[href]:not(...) instead.

Comment: there is also  href="javascript:void(0)"