# Javascript Smooth Scrolling Exception

Tags: javascript, exception, navigation, href, smoothing

I need some help with a javascript function. Somewhere I've found this smooth scrolling code:

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top //-65 //fixed header height
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }/**/
        }
      });
    });
```

It works fine, however I have on the same page(s) a dropdown nav, and it uses the anchor link (#nav) to show/hide the first level elements of nav on mobiles. With that javascript above, this show/hide function doesn't work, so I need to exclude the #nav href in this JS code. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676962/anotanothref-selector

Comment: Don't use an anchor element unless you actually intend it to be an anchor. Sounds like your nav toggler should just be a `<button>` with the appropriate click handler